# How to obtain all the elements with the same tag name by namespace?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to obtain the list of `url` attribute of all `<media:content/>` elements:

This is my XML:

```
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <media:group>
                <media:content url='https://valor'/>
            </media:group>
        </item>
        <item>
            <media:group>
                <media:content url='https://valor'/>
            </media:group>
        </item>    
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I tried this, but `contents.getLength()` returns 0 elements

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
NodeList contents = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", "content");
```

Also I tried to use XPath... but again, `contents.getLength()` returns 0 elements

```
XPathFactory factory2 = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory2.newXPath();
// XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//content"); 
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[name()='content']");
NodeList contents = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

suggestions?

Comment: I thought that your xpath should work because it has default behavior when namespace awareness is not enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set `factory.setNamespaceAware(true)`. Then the `getElementsByTagNameNS` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! BTW I asked the same question on stack overflow in spanish, If you want to support us, please answer on there too (in english), I will translate the answer for you: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6760